# asp.net gridview checkbox checked always false

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a `CheckBox` inside a GridView. When I click on *Save* button `Checkbox.checked` property is always false.

This is my code:

```
ArrayList productsToDelete = new ArrayList();

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewSubmit.Rows)
{

    CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)GridViewSubmit.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("chkDelete");
    if (chkDelete != null)
    {
       if (chkDelete.Checked)
       {

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: Could you show the entire aspx.cs class please? Looks like you are trying to get the state of the checkbox before the LoadViewState.

Comment: is this grid inside update panel and save button outside it ?

Comment: can you also tell us whether you have the viewstate enabled or disabled?

Comment: can you please you show you page load method? I suspect you have not checked ispostback.